# Split UTF-16 String into single chars/strings

Tags: java, utf-16

I have string that looks like this `abc` and I want to split it to single chars/strings.

```
static List<String> split(String text ) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(text.length());
    for(int i = 0; i < text.length() ; i++) {
        list.add(text.substring(i, i + 1));
    }
    return list;
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    split("a\uD83D\uDC4Fb\uD83D\uDE42c")
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

As you might already notice instead of  and  I'm getting two weird characters:

```
a
?
?
b
?
?
c
```

Comment: Those are not UTF-16 characters, that's the problem. Those are UTF-32 code points.

Comment: As the answers show, that can be done reasonably easily. Once you try to dabble into combining characters that render to single glyphs though, it becomes a whole other kind of hell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [Character and String APIs docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/characterClass.html) you need to use code points to correctly handle the UTF multi-byte sequences.

```
"abc".codePoints().mapToObj(Character::toChars).forEach(System.out::println);
```

will output

```
a

b

c
```

Comment: And how can I change those ```codePoints``` into strings?

Answer (score 6):

The following will do the job:

```
List<String> split(String text) {
    return text.codePoints()
            .mapToObj(Character::toChars)
            .map(String::valueOf)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an Open source MgntUtils library (written by me) that has a utility that translates any string into unicodes and vise-versa (handling correctly code-points) this can help you handling your problem as well as understand the internal work going on behind the sciences. Here is an example:

the code below

```
String result = "abc";
result = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.encodeStringToUnicodeSequence(result);
System.out.println(result);
result = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.decodeUnicodeSequenceToString(result);
System.out.println(result);
```

would produce the following:

```
\u0061\u1f44f\u0062\u1f642\u0063
abc
```

Here is te link to the article that explains about the MgntUtils library and where to get it (including javadoc and source code): [Open Source Java library with stack trace filtering, Silent String parsing Unicode converter and Version comparison](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-source-java-library-some-useful-utilities-michael-gantman/). Look for paragraph "**String Unicode converter**"